# What is the better way of printing and concatinating translated variables in twig?

Tags: html, twig, string-concatenation

Lets say i have a setup similar to this, translated strings, variables and seperators (space) mixed in one print.

```
{{ "app.user.welcometxt"|trans ~" "~ app.user.name ~" "~ app.user.lastname }}
```

Is this a good practice?
Or should i put the variables in seperate statements and print one after another?

```
{{ "app.user.welcometext"|trans }} {{ app.user.name }} {{ app.user.lastname }}
```

What is the best way to go about this?
What is the fastest, or best for performance?

Answer (score 0):

While I personally think the explicit form is much more readable, the readability of different code-styles is a very opinionated thing.

Performance-wise the explicit form ...

```
{{ "app.user.welcometext"|trans }} {{ app.user.name }} {{ app.user.lastname }}
```

... is definitely better because Twig doesn't have to concatenate the 3 strings before they get replaced. I'd strongly recommend you to let Twig internally handle this type of "optimization".

A more flexible way to output a user greeting with Twig would be the following:

```
{% trans with {'%name%': user.name, '%lastname%': user.lastname} from 'app' %}
  {{- app.user.welcometext -}}
{% endtrans %}
```

Then set the welcome text to something like `Hello %name% %lastname%`.

This will allow you to easily append more text (i.e. using a greeting like `Hello %name% %lastname%. How are you feeling today?`) **without** having to change your template.